# angular double braces expression treated as string

Tags: angularjs

im taking from my server a list of workers and try to open bootstrap modal with a specific worker details according to the click of the user:

```html
<tr ng-repeat="worker in workers">
 <td>{{worker.firstName}}</td>
 <td class="center">{{worker.lastName}}</td>       
 <td class="center">
  <a class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#workerModal" ng-click="workerInfo('{{worker.id}}')">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in white" >
  </a>
 </td>
 <td style="display: none;">{{worker.id}}</td> 
</tr>
```

but the ng-click func pass to workerInfo the string "{{worker.id}" instead of sending the worker id why is it happening?

Comment: workerInfo(worker.id)

Comment: `ng-click` is not a javascript function call, it is an angular directive that accepts an expression.  it is not necessary to interpolate the expression;  In fact, interpolating the expression won't work because the directive is resolved before interpolation happens. instead of `workerInfo('{{worker.id}}')`, you should simply use `workerInfo(worker.id)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling a controller function in `ng-click` there is no need for interpolation. Like this:

```
ng-click="workerInfo(worker.id)"
```